# What will happen if I install Wayland?

Tags: 11.10, wayland

I am curious about the progress being made with [Wayland](https://launchpad.net/wayland) and would like to perhaps give it a spin. According to the Launchpad page, it is packaged in Oneiric (and has actually been packaged since Natty). Therefore I can simply install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install wayland-demos
```

**However,** I don't know what will happen if I install it. Will I need to manually launch it? Will it play nice with X configuration files and settings? Will anything break?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing happens. You will just be able to run some demos (see `/usr/share/doc/wayland-demos/README.Debian` for how to start them).